# Value Error: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been creating an application that will run just like **Microsoft Notepad**. My program comprises of the following file and folder:

```
libs (Folder)
scripts (Folder)
test.py
```

The test.py is the file in which I am trying the following code:

```
from .libs import tkinter
from .libs import pyglet
from .libs import threading

test_window = Tk()

test_window.mainloop()
```

In the folder `libs` I have added the modules that are required in the application.
Example: Tkinter, Pyglet and Threading

When I am trying to import them into test.py using the code above and then running the program. I see the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Bhavyadeep\Desktop\NuclearPad\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .libs import tkinter
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

> I don't really know how I solve this problem. Is it because I added the module in the folder where Import in not available? Or is it because I did something wrong in this module folder copying-pasting to a folder not at Python's `PATH`?

Comment: Why do you appear to be importing third party packages from a separate folder? are you using a virtual environment? does `import tkinter` not work?

Comment: This application is actually not only for me. I would give it to my friends for testing. Well for that they would want to install modules first before actually using the software. I don't want them to do that. The program will have the modules present already and won't need installation thus I have made a folder for those modules.

I haven't been using any virtual environment currently. And also `import tkinter` will import it from the python's `PATH` that was set during Python's installation and not from the folder I want to.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` it's that simple to share the required libraries... Anyway you get the error because the folder `test.py` is present in is not a module. To make it a module you need to add an `__init__.py` file to the folder. But I would not recommend this bad approach of putting 3rd party libraries in a folder to share them. Simply share your requirements file.

Comment: Well the `__init__.py` addition doesn't help. I tried it. And I didn't get the `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` thing.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` this will create a file `requirements.txt` from the output given by `pip freeze`. Now `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install all the packages listed in `requirements.txt`. Your libs folder might also not have `__init__.py` it would also need the file to make it a package

Comment: Well it would require them to have python installed right?

Comment: So you plan to use something like `pyinstaller` to package your script so it can be run as a .exe file? If so I think that pyinstaller packages your required modules does it not

Comment: I am not sure I know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from .libs import tkinter
```

Means "import tkinter from the package called lib which is located in the same directory as **file** (this script)"

so your first line should say something like

```
test_window = tkinter.Tk()
```

unless you use either of the following:

```
from .libs.tkinter import *
from .libs.tkinter import Tk
```

---

The error is likely due to you using relative import syntax from within the script you are trying to execute. Remove the leading dots in order to execute `test.py`, otherwise append its directory to `sys.path` or use `site.addsitedir(path_to_directory_containing_test_py)` and import it as follows `import test`.

With that said, you should not call the module's file `test.py` because there is already something with that name in python's default Lib directory or builtins. If you insist, there should be a hacky way to get it done without changing the name through importlib.

As for why this error occurs, I think it's because the interpreter is designed to execute scripts but not modules/packages whose contents are placed in .pyc files in `__pycache__`s when imported.

---

In order to import from `scripts or libs`, they must be packages. In order to turn them into packages you must add `__init__.py` files to them.

---

### *Lastly, It's a pretty terrible idea to place third-party libraries in your source like this. At the very least you should have installed them properly on your machine and then copied their sources from `site-packages`/the equivalent for `venv`s, which will fail if they use any executables and/or have any external dependencies*

[Documentation for distributing python packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)